# Gulp watch only run once with one file

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

There are a lot of questions on this topic. I have been through them and not found an answer, though located the specific issue.

The following watch will only execute `et-js` the first time that is modified:

```
gulp.watch( './js/et.js' ).on( 'change', gulp.series( 'et-js' ) );
```

It will only run every time the file(s) are modified if it has more than one file suplpied, e.g.

```
gulp.watch( ['./js/et.js', './js/tu.js'] ).on( 'change', gulp.series( 'et-js' ) );
```

This doesn't run on every modification either:

```
gulp.watch( ['./js/et.js'] ).on( 'change', gulp.series( 'et-js' ) );
```

Any ideas what the issue is?

Gulp version:

CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.0

Comment: You should show your entire gulpfile.js too if that isn't too long, especially the `et-js` task.

Comment: For me it turns out that it would only run once if specific files are listed in watch, e.g. js/et.js. If js/*.js is used - it works.